# Sharing mysql connection between main module and threads causing data result mismatch

Tags: python, mysql

This is my MySQL class shared between multiple other classes that needs SQL connections:

```
class mysqlAssist():
    def __init__(self):
        self.con = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","user","pass","DB",3306, charset="utf8")
        self.con.autocommit(True)

    @contextmanager
    def cursor(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        c = self.con.cursor( *args, **kwargs)
        try:
            yield c
        finally:
            c.close()

    def fetchOne(self, _sql):
        with self.cursor() as c:
            try:
                c.execute(_sql)
                return c.fetchone()
            except (MySQLdb.Error, MySQLdb.Warning) as e:
                print(e)


    def fetchAll(self, _sql):
        with self.cursor( MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor ) as c:
            try:
                c.execute(_sql)
                return c.fetchall()
            except (MySQLdb.Error, MySQLdb.Warning) as e:
                print(e)
```

The object is created in Main module

`mysql_assist = mysqlAssist();`

My **main** module executes the following two SQL queries:

mysql_assist.fetchOne:

```sql
SELECT `start_time`, `stop_time`, `AHC_DAY` FROM `_management` WHERE `_active` = '1'
```

mysql_assist.fetchAll:

```sql
SELECT _id, _desc, _show_type, _web_manage, _lastevent, _lastevent=max_lastevent 
            AS _latest FROM `_setup` CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(_lastevent) as max_lastevent FROM _setup) m
```

The second query result looks like this:

```
+---------+-------------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+-------------+
|     _id |     _desc         |  _show_type    |     _web_manage |     _lastevent |     _latest |
+---------+-------------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+-------------+
| here>11  | A                 |              1 |               1 |     1633107217 |           0 |
|       6 | B                 |              1 |               0 |     1633168302 |           0 |
|      12 | C                 |              0 |               0 |     1633169804 |           1 |
|      16 | D                 |              0 |               1 |     1632480486 |           0 |
|      19 | E                 |              0 |               0 |     1632549333 |           0 |
|      26 | F                 |              0 |               0 |     1631868026 |           0 |
|      25 | G                 |              1 |               0 |     1633168303 |           0 |
|      27 | H                 |              1 |               1 |     1632992896 |           0 |
+---------+-------------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+-------------+
```

Now the problem: rarely and occasionally, the first query returns result of the second query in specific value: `11` which is the first line and first column result of the second query. Evidence of the problem is that my traceback shows following error as it is expecting completely different result (date) then pure number: `ERROR - time data '11' does not match format '%H:%M:%S'`, so indeed this not the expected result from the database.

This is happening when 2nd query is executed as Thread using previously created connection object `mysql_assist`.

What is correct approach to handle MYSQL connections in Threads?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL connections can only have one cursor — one active query — at a time. But connections are not very expensive, so you can use a separate one for each query you need to run concurrently.

Comment: ok, but my code closes cursor after every query, so there should not be situation that two cursors are opened. The number `11` occupies position 0 in array returned, that was actually supposed to be reserved for first query

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in sharing mysql object created in `main` module in `Threads`. When mysql object was re-used in Threading function, then it produced unexpected mysql results. Now everytime I am starting new Thread, I am firstly creating new mysql connection object, that is used in target Thread. It seems that issue has gone completely, but is this the correct way of handling mysql connection in Threads ?